# How to pass data from a BottomSheetFragment to another fragment?

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, bottom-sheet, bottomsheetdialogfragment

I have an `Activity`, called 'HomeActivity', where I have a bottom navigation menu and four fragments. The activity has a `FloatingActionButton` and when I hit this, it opens a `bottomSheetFragment` which contain a `RecyclerView` and when I hit an item from it, I want some values to send to the `fragment` ('HomeFragment') which is part of the 'HomeActivity'

After doing a lot of searches online, I have done the following but I am not able to get the data in the `fragment`.

Following is the `fragment` from which I want to send the data.

'HomeBottomSheetFragment.kt'

```
        class HomeBottomSheetFragment: BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
    
        private lateinit var binding: FragmentHomeBottomSheetBinding
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    
            FirestoreClass().getCategoryList(this)
    
        }
    
        override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
        ): View {
            binding = FragmentHomeBottomSheetBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
            return binding.root
        }
    
    fun successCategoryList(categoryList: ArrayList<ProdCategories>) {

        binding.rvHomeCategories.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        binding.rvHomeCategories.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 4)
        binding.rvHomeCategories.setHasFixedSize(true)
        val categoryAdapter = CategoryListAdapter(requireContext(), categoryList)
        binding.rvHomeCategories.adapter = categoryAdapter

        categoryAdapter.setOnClickListener(object :CategoryListAdapter.OnClickListener{
            override fun onClick(position: Int, category: ProdCategories) {

                val myFragment = HomeFragment()
                val bundle = Bundle()
                bundle.putString("category", category.category_name)
                myFragment.arguments = bundle    
                fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment,HomeFragment())?.commit()
            }
        })

    }

}
```

Following is the adapter of the above fragment ('HomeBottomSheetFragment.kt'), 'CategoryListAdapter.kt'.

```
open class CategoryListAdapter(private val context: Context, private var list: ArrayList<ProdCategories>)
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    private var onClickListener: OnClickListener? = null

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return MyViewHolder(
            HomeBottomsheetCategoryListLayoutBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(
                    parent.context
                ), parent, false
            )
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val model = list[position]

        if (holder is MyViewHolder) {

            GlideLoader(context).loadProductPicture(model.category_image, holder.binding.ivCategoryImage)
            holder.binding.tvCategoryName.text=model.category_name
        }

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            if (onClickListener != null) {
                onClickListener!!.onClick(position, model)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.size
    }

    fun setOnClickListener(onClickListener: OnClickListener) {
        this.onClickListener = onClickListener
    }

    interface OnClickListener{
        fun onClick(position: Int, category: ProdCategories)
    }

    private class MyViewHolder(val binding: HomeBottomsheetCategoryListLayoutBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

}
```

Following is the `fragment` where I want to receive the data.

```
class HomeFragment : BaseFragment() {

private var filterCategory: String?= null

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        val bundle = this.arguments
        if (bundle!=null) {
            filterCategory = bundle.getString("category")
        }

        return binding.root
    }
}
```

All I know is that I am not doing things right, please help me fix it.

Comment: Why are you implementing your interface in both activity and fragment? What is `val myFragment = HomeFragment()` for?

Comment: First I added it only in the activity, since that was not working I tried it adding in the fragment. That too didn't work. I know I was not able to get my interface work properly, so I tried with 'bundle'. I was not successful either way. Can you tell me how to make this right? Thanks.

Comment: You have set the listener only in the BottomSheet so only that will be invoked. Where exactly do you want to send the data?

Comment: I want to send data from the 'CategoryListAdapter' to 'HomeFragment'. The data I want to send is the position and model.

Comment: You already have the data in `HomeBottomSheetFragment`. Now you want to send this to `HomeFragment`, right?

Comment: How are these two related? Did you navigate from HomeFragment to HomeBottomSheetFragment? Are you using Navigation Library in you project?

Comment: @ArpitShukla, My question is revised, please check now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line,
`fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment,HomeFragment())?.commit()`

Replace `HomeFragment()` with `myFragment` because that's where you are attaching the bundle.

See if this solves your problem.

Comment: Awesome, it worked but the bottom sheet is not getting closed. How can I close this when I hit an item in it? Thanks.

Comment: Call `dismiss()`

Comment: Can you take a look at this, please? https://stackoverflow.com/q/70134116/13935956